# Simplicial categories and simplicial objectcs. HTT Remark 1.1.4.2

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

In Lurie's HTT, Remark 1.1.4.2. says that:
every simplicial category can be regarded as a simplicial object in the category $\textbf{Cat}$. Conversely, a simplicial object of $\textbf{Cat}$ arises from a simplicial category if and only if the underlying simplicial set of objects is constant.

Do you have any hints?

Comment: Can you provide exact definitions?

Comment: A simplicial category is a category wich is enriched over the category of simplicial sets. A simplicial object in $\textbf{Cat}$ is a functor $\Delta^{op}\to \textbf{Cat}$.

Answer (score 4):

Remark that a simplicial object in $\mathbf{Cat}$ is the same thing as a category internal to $\mathbf{sSet}$. This way, you should see the connection more easily. Indeed, a category internal to $\mathbf{sSet}$ is almost the same thing as a simplicial category except that the objects now forms a *space* (by which I mean a simplicial set) instead of a mere sets. Lurie's remark is just that sets can be viewed as discrete spaces.

Of course, you should make all that formal. (You only asked for hints, so I didn't go into details.)

---

Side note : "simplicial category" is kind of ambiguous, even if I agree with the meaning you put behind the name; "category enriched over simplical sets" does not leave any doubt about what you mean.

Comment: Thank You, I will work on your hint!!!!